# Возможно ли умножение внутри "INSERT...VALUES"?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

В данной таблице (Лот поставки) стоимость заказа напрямую зависит от количества и типа товара.

```
    CREATE TABLE Order_lot 
(
  ID_Order_Lot INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ID_Product INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(ID_Product),
  Amount INT,
  Order_price Money,
  ID_Order INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES _Order(ID_Order)
);
```

Сейчас таблица заполняется по таким правилам (прайс заполняется нулями):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли добавить функцию  при первичном заполнении, что-то вроде:

```
INSERT...[x.a][x.b][x.c] VALUES (5, 10, x.a*x.b)
```

или же необходимо создавать отдельный запрос/результирующую таблицу(select...where).

Comment: `Use Shops_net
UPDATE Order_lot SET 
Order_price = Order_lot.Amount * Product.Pr_Price From Product INNER JOIN Order_lot ON  (Order_lot.ID_Product = Product.ID_Product)
     
Select Order_lot.*, Pr_price From Order_lot,Product Where Order_Lot.ID_Product = Product.ID_Product`
Тот самый запрос

Comment: Используйте вычисляемый столбец, если в С всегда должно находиться произведение А*В.

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko Спасибо )) Сложно искать информацию про сам не знаешь что )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операндом в списке значений VALUES должно быть выражение, результатом которого является скалярное значение (требуемого типа). А что это за выражение - одиночный литерал, арифметическое выражение или даже подзапрос - абсолютно неважно.

Однако используемые в выражении значения должны быть достижимы (находиться в области видимости) - увы, значения других полей создаваемой записи к таковым не относятся.

Тем не менее требуемое - возможно. Следует использовать `INSERT .. SET`:

```
INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) 
SET a = 5, 
    b = 10, 
    с = a * b;
```

В такой форме INSERT можно в выражении ссылаться на значения полей вставляемой записи, если эти значения присвоены выше по тексту.